# Barcode decoding

Tags: sql, barcode

I am building a pos system.
What i need is that user scans a packet of items.
That items gives information about quantity of items in the packet.
Now when I search in Database I can't search barcode of a packet because i want to sell 1 item from the packet.
I want that query.

for example if barcode is 12345 then i will search like barcode like '12345%' 
where '12345' is barcode of the packet and numbers after '12345' determines that item is from that packet.
I hope i explain my question.

Comment: The amount is not part of the bar code. So why are you combining the bar code and amount in one field. The barcode will not magically update when you remove a item form the package... So I guess you have to do something with your on your requirements before you start any coding.

Comment: You can have weight encoded in a barcode as well as price, but as already mentioned by Peter not the content of the package. Usually you have some kind of mapping table, where each barcode is assigned to a combination of various settings, such as article number, selling variant (e.g. certain flavour of bubblegum) and selling unit (1 package of 10 stripes, 1 box of 10 packages, 1 big box of 10 boxes etc.). However, you MIGHT be able to encode this kind of data already in your barcode, but then you will need to use EAN-128, whicht might be way oversized for your requirement.

Comment: You have a package of 6 bottles of milk. Package has barcode `12345`. Bottles of milk have barcodes `123451`, `123452`, `123453`, etc. You sell 1 bottle of milk so you scan barcode `123451`, and you want to know how to get BBDD package `12345`. Is that your question?

Comment: Yes walen this is my question.